# Usage of the phrasal verb "to wind down"

Tags: word-usage

-Barclays to *wind down* commodities trading. (from Financial Times, April 21st)

-Senate Bill seeks to *wind down* Fannie Mae in five years.(Bloomberg, March 17th)

Is the use of *to wind down*  becoming more frequent also in less informal contexts? Plus, could this expression be used in a intransitive way?

Answer (score 1):

*wind down* is used both as a transitive and an intransitive verb.

> ***[wind down](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/wind-down)***
>   [intransitive/transitive] to end, or to finish something gradually
>   *The party started to wind down around 2:00 a.m.*
>   *The U.N. has decided to wind down the peacekeeping mission.*
>   **a**.
>   to gradually reduce work before stopping completely
>   *The factory will wind down production before closing next year.*

Comment: Can you add your source pls.

Comment: @Josh61 Just left-click on the phrase (in red) or right-click & select open-in-new-tab!